What is the correct structure of a multi-language monorepo on Nx?
I'm building an airline booking site, i need to handle user registration, authentication, booking, seatmap, etc. I'm using 2 API's in 2 languages (.NET in a API that handles the flight search, booking and payment; and JS in another API for real-time seat map updates and managing caching layers for repeated flight searches) + a frontend component with NextJS and Tailwind.
I'm trying to use a monorepo with Nx but i'm confused with the way that is supposed to be organized.
So far i have created 3 apps (api-js, api-dotnet, frontend) with this structure:
/monorepo-root
├── /apps                   # Contains minimal, app-specific setup
│   ├── /frontend           # Entry point for the frontend (Next.js)
│   ├── /api-js             # Node.js API with REST operations
│   ├── /api-dotnet         # .NET API REST
├── /libs                   # Reusable code
│   ├── /ui                 # Shared UI components
│   │   ├── /components     # Reusable UI elements like buttons, modals
│   │   └── /layouts        # Shared page layouts
│   ├── /utils              # Shared utilities and helper functions
        ├── /date           # Date manipulation helpers


Each API has inside its own Class models, Controllers, etc.
But looking on a website it states that:

Nx has a concept of Apps and Libs. Apps can be seen as deployable artifacts and libs include most of the actual code and the business logic. It’s nevertheless not unusual, when first starting to work with Nx, to put a lot of code into your Apps and to use libs only for shared code. But when you are switching to a Nx Monorepo, you should try to structure your repository “the Nx way”. That means that you should put almost no code at all into your apps and have almost all the code located in your libs. Even code that won’t be shared between apps should be put into libs. That might seem a bit counter intuitive at first, but if you apply that structure it will help you keep your monorepo organized. Plus, that way you are well prepared if it becomes necessary for a lib to be shared or reused somewhere else in the future. If you use a consistent folder structure and naming strategy for your libs you will end up with a monorepo that’ll be a pleasure to work in.

So is this structure correct?:
/monorepo-root
├── /apps
|     ├── api-dotnet
│     |   ├── Program.cs                 # Bootstrapping the app
│     |   ├── Startup.cs (optional)      # Additional app configuration if needed
│     |   ├── appsettings.json           # App-specific configuration
│     |   ├── All Visual Studio Created files and folders (.csproj, bin, obj, etc)
│     |
|     ├── api-js
|     |   ├── index.js
|
├── /libs                   
│   ├── /ui                 # Shared UI components
│   │   ├── /components     # Reusable UI elements like buttons, modals
│   │   └── /layouts        # Shared page layouts
│   ├── /utils              # Shared utilities and helper functions
|   |   ├── /date           # Date manipulation helpers
│   ├── /features           # App-specific features, organized by domain
│   │   ├── /auth           # Authentication logic (e.g., login, register)
│   │   ├── /flight-search  # Flight search feature logic
│   │   └── /profile        # User profile management
│   └── /data-access        # Data-related code like database models, services
│       ├── /frontend-api   # Frontend API services
│       ├── /api-js-models  # Models and services for the Node.js API
│       └── /api-dotnet     # Data-related logic for .NET


any updates on this?
